# Amplitude of complex exponential function

Tags: complex-numbers

Suppose that the real part of a complex exponential function has a real amplitude and the imaginary part also has the same real amplitude. Does this mean that the complex exponential function that is composed of them has the same real amplitude? Or does it have complex amplitude because it is somehow composed of two amplitudes?

Comment: How do you define complex amplitude? In general, how do you compare two complex numbers?

Comment: complex amplitude is a complex number before complex exponential function